# Vue Old Array Mirroring New Array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects, vue-reactivity

I have two arrays declared in my data

```
data() {
        return {
            infeed_data:[],
            infeed_model:[],
        }
    },
```

Once the page is mounted, the following method is kicked off

```
mounted() {
        this.get_rolls_infeed()

    },
```

This method makes a call to my api, then assigns the response to both infeed_data and infeed_model. I then do a for loop and create new key/values on the infeed_model, however the new key/values show up in the infeed_data.

```
get_rolls_infeed(){
            var vthis = this;
            axios.post(myapiurl)
            .then(function(response){

                vthis.infeed_data = response.data[0]
                vthis.infeed_model = response.data[0]

                vthis.infeed_model.forEach(function(record, index){
                   vthis.infeed_model[index].usage_type = 0
                })

            })
        },
```

My Vue html

```
<b>Infeed Data</b>
<p>{{infeed_data}}</p>

<br />

<b>Infeed Model</p>
<p>{{infeed_model}}</p>
```

Rendered html to show how _data is mirroring _model
[image: Rendered html]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to do this instead of your code?

```
vthis.infeed_data = response.data[0];
vthis.infeed_model = response.data[0].slice();
```

Comment: Looks like this didn't work either. `usage_type` still appears in the infeed_data.

Comment: @AndrewBaker , are you sure `usage_type` is absent witin `response.data[0]`?

Comment: Absolutely sure. It doesn’t exist in response from the api. I want to add it to a new array which I will submit to api which will point to a different db.

Comment: @AndrewBaker, no. I am talking about updates within my answer.

Comment: @AndrewBaker, does my update to answer help to solve your issue?